# When running a program on Eclipse IDE, shows a fatal error

Tags: java, eclipse

The error:
[image: The error]

My eclipse.ini looks like this. I have no idea why the error shows up. i have jdk installed as well.

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.6.100.v20201223-0822.jar
--launcher.library
C:\Users\Swamy\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.2.100.v20210209-1541
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
-showsplash
C:\Users\Swamy\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.epp.package.common_4.19.0.20210311-1200
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=11
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace
-Dsun.java.command=Eclipse
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=11
-Dosgi.dataAreaRequiresExplicitInit=true
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.graphics.Resource.reportNonDisposed=true
-Xms256m
-Xmx2048m
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Declipse.p2.max.threads=10
-Doomph.update.url=http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest
-Doomph.redirection.index.redirection=index:/->http://git.eclipse.org/c/oomph/org.eclipse.oomph.git/plain/setups/
```

Comment: The `eclipse.ini` is to run Eclipse, but you seem to have the problem when running your code, right? So show your run configuration and what the _Show Command Line_ button tells.